# AWS-SDK S3 deleteObjects Returning MalformedXML?

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mongoose

Using the aws-sdk (2.0.18) for node.js, i'm trying to delete multiple objects using the `deleteObjects` method.

```
delete: function (objects, callback) {
  var s3delete = new AWS.S3();
  var params = {
    Bucket: config.s3.bucket,
    Delete: {
      Objects: objects
    }
  };
  s3delete.deleteObjects(params, function (err, deleted) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
      return callback(err);
    }
    return callback(null, deleted);
  });
}
```

My params object looks like this:

```
{ Bucket: 'bucketname',
  Delete: { 
    Objects:[
      {"Key":"folder/file.extension"},
      {"Key":"folder/file.extension"},
      {"Key":"folder/file.extension"},
      {"Key":"folder/file.extension"},
      {"Key":"folder/file.extension"},
      {"Key":"folder/file.extension"},
      {"Key":"folder/file.extension"}
    ]
  }
}
```

This returns the following error:

```
{
  message: "The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema",
  code: "MalformedXML",
  time: "2014-10-11T10:35:52.525Z",
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false
}
```

According to the [API spec](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObjects-property), this should work. FYI: I'm passing in the `objects` argument from a Mongoose Model, it is stored as Mixed in Mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by Mongoose returning malformed JSON objects in the original `objects` array.

In order to fix this specifically, I had to create a new Object and push them to a new array, in this specific case:

```
var s3Objects = [];

objects.forEach(function(ele, index, arr) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + ele.Key);
  var thisKey = {
    Key: ele.Key
  };
  s3Objects.push(thisKey);
});
```

Then passed in `s3Objects` to the params:

```
var params = {
  Bucket: config.s3.bucket,
  Delete: {
    Objects: properObjects
  }
};
```

It now works.